# Insert a .png file inside ggplot with Dates in x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, png

I have the dataframe below:

```
d1_7<-structure(list(conm = c("Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", 
"Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", 
"Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", 
"Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", 
"Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", 
"Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc", "Facebook Inc"), datadate = structure(c(14974, 
14974, 15339, 15339, 15705, 15705, 16070, 16070, 16435, 16435, 
16800, 16800, 17166, 17166, 17531, 17531, 17896, 17896, 18261, 
18261, 18627, 18627), label = "Data Date", format.stata = "%td", class = "Date"), 
    fin_var = c("mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", 
    "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", 
    "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", 
    "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale"), fin_value = c(NA, 
    1974, NA, 3711, 60321.3848471, 5089, 132250.58, 7872, 203944.28, 
    12466, 293361.98, 17928, 329388.15, 27638, 511910.46, 40653, 
    378850.1, 55838, 585783.5, 70697, 778779.16, 85965)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

and I want to put a .png inside my ggplot like:

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(png)
library(ggplot2)
mypng <- readPNG('C:/Users/User/Documents/Avilla ggplot/mark-zuckerberg-celebrity-mask.png')


plot <- ggplot(d1_7, aes(x = datadate, y = fin_value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = conm))+
  facet_wrap(~conm,ncol=1)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  ylab('Profits in $ million')+
  xlab('Fiscal Year')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#5cc9f5"))
plot+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title=""))+annotation_raster(mypng, ymin = 500000,ymax= 600000,xmin = 2014,xmax = 2015)
```

I believe that I cannot display it because `xmin` and `xmax` cannot accept dates as inputs.
[image]

Comment: Please don't include `library(tidyverse)` in your questions. Some people do not want to install or load this huge meta-package. Load the specific package (which is no package in this example) that is actually needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe that I cannot display it because xmin and xmax cannot accept dates as inputs.

That's incorrect. You just don't pass dates.

```
plot+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title=""))+
  annotation_raster(mypng, ymin = 500000,ymax= 600000,
                    xmin = as.Date("2014-01-01"),xmax = as.Date("2015-01-01"))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 2):

Either specify the date `as.Date` or pass the raw values to xmin and xmax.

```
# library(tidyverse)
library(png)
library(ggplot2)
mypng <- readPNG('~/Desktop/tt.png')


plot <- ggplot(d1_7, aes(x = datadate, y = fin_value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = conm))+
  facet_wrap(~conm,ncol=1)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  ylab('Profits in $ million')+
  xlab('Fiscal Year')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#5cc9f5"))
plot+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title=""))+annotation_raster(mypng, ymin = 350000,ymax= 800000,xmin = 16000,xmax = 17000)
```

[image]